# ZKP in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, bitcoin

I'm using the fabcar project: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk

It uses HyperLedger 1.4.1. I would like to know a bit more about privacy-enhancing solutions.

How is Zero Knowledge Proof (ZKP) implemented?
Are there any other techniques or solutions implemented?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it using Identity Mixer as stated by IBM Hyperledger Dcoumentation.But I have not come across  any working example so far neither from IBM Hypeledger site nor any other unofficial dev blogs.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/idemix.html